# ASP.NET: Access Child control Inside IFrame in Parent Page

Tags: iframe, c#-3.0, asp.net-3.5

I have a 1st page in which i have a IFrame control. Inside iFrame, i opened 2nd page. Now i want to access the control values of 2nd Page in 1st page Code behind.

I am not able to access. I am using Dot Net Framework 3.5

Please help me for it...

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking to do is not possible by any normal means. The two IFrames represent different web requests and one request has no idea about the other request.

It's no different than asking for one request to know about the controls from the previous page the user was on, which is also of course not possible.

Comment: I think the Dot Net Framework 4.0 supports to do the above. But i am not able to do in Dot Net Framework 3.5. The issue is related to Permission to access the controls in Iframe.

Comment: Nope, this doesn't have to do with permissions and it doesn't have to do with which version of .NET you are using. Every web request is its own page and has its own control tree. One GET request does not ever have access to the control tree of another GET request. What exactly are you trying to do? There might be another solution that doesn't involve what you're asking to do here.

Comment: I think the example which i am attaching below is somewhat near to my problem's Solution: http://shawpnendu.blogspot.com/2010/09/jquery-to-get-set-read-access-iframe.html